Is there a way to use TF.exe history to get the history as well as related work items to the change sets?
I know tf.exe can get the history, but is there a way to get the history that includes the date/time, comment, and related work items linked to the changeset?
history $/ /r /format:brief /noprompt
This returns most of what I want but need the related work items too

You can try like as below:

You can get the list of Changesets using the "tf history" command.

Then you can get the Date, Comment and associated Work Items of each Changeset using the "tf changeset" command.



You just need a loop to read each Changeset from the list and run the "tf changeset" command for each one.


Thanks, was hoping for something I could just run and output to a comma-delimited file or something so put in a spreadsheet.

@ChrisWard, I did not figure out a way to let the command to output to a comma-delimited file or something so put in a spreadsheet. you might try to let the "tf changeset" command to output to a text file for each changeset like as the following command "tf changeset 78 /noprompt | Out-File -FilePath changeset78.txt".

Yea but with over 1000 changesets that is going to take a while.  I tried doing it from code too but I couldn't get the authentication to work from code no matter what I tried.

@ChrisWard, To use the tf command, you need to use the 'tf workspace' command to map the workspace on the machine if no workspace mapped. And you can use the 'tf workspaces' to list all the mapped workspaces and switch to a workspace.

the workspace is already mapped your commend doesn't answer my question which is to get a list of every linked work item and it's description from history.

@ChrisWard May I know how you authenticated your access in your code? Can you please share your code so that we can test and research to see if there's way to achieve your requirements?

@ChrisWard, What type of code do you want to use to call the tf command?
